# Excel Formula - using IF AND/OR in same function

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Looking for a formula that will calculate if/and/or:

Column A is Date item is Due
Column B is Time item is Due
Column C is Actual Date item completed
Column D is Actual Time item completed

I have the formula for when if the date expectation is met: =(if(C1<=A1,"Yes", "No")

How do I calculate if the date expectation was met, but not the time expectation? I.E. the item was delivered on the correct date, but did not meet the time standard?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

IF(C1<=A1,if(b1<=d1,”Yes”,”No T”),”No D”)

Sorry, can’t test as am on a smartphone...

Answer (score 1):

You put the `AND` in the `logical test` part of the `IF` statement.

`=IF(AND(logical 1, logical 2), outcome if both are true, outcome if either are false)`

That way, you need to satisfy both the date and time requirements before a True value will be given.

`=IF(AND(C2 <= A2, D2 <= B2), "YES", "NO")`

This will work if the item is delivered on, or before the required day AND the time it is delivered is also before the required time.

What happens if the item is delivered before it is due, but at a time that is later than it is due?

You could either put date and time in the same field or, you could add an `OR` operator in there.

`=IF(OR(AND(C2 <= A2, D2 <= B2), C2 < A2), "YES", "NO")`

Add the `OR` allows you to say that you don't care about the time it is delivered if the item is delivered before the due delivery date, but you do care about the time if it delivered on the due date.